# Tensorflow on Raspberry Pi Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, tensorflow-serving

I have a python script that works without any errors on my desktop. When I try to run it on my raspberry pi, I encounter an error.

To install tensorflow on the raspberry pi for python 3.5, I followed this tutorial: https://petewarden.com/2017/08/20/cross-compiling-tensorflow-for-the-raspberry-pi/ There is no offical binary for tensorflow and python 3.5 and I had errors when I tried to compile it myself. The tutorial suggest to just install tensorflow from the Python 3.4 binary.

> If you’re running Python 3.5, you can use the Python 3.4 wheel but with a
>   slight change to the file name, since that encodes the version. You
>   will see a couple of warnings every time you import tensorflow, but it
>   should work correctly.

Here is the error I am encountering:

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.4 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.5
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 432, got 412
  return f(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 93, in <module>
    model = FastPredict(tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=convolutional_neural_network, model_dir="tmp"))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/lazy_loader.py", line 42, in _load
    module = importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 673, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python import tfe as eager
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/tfe.py", line 76, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.eager.python.datasets import Iterator
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/eager/python/datasets.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops import prefetching_ops
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/prefetching_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
    resource_loader.get_path_to_datafile("../../_prefetching_ops.so"))
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/util/loader.py", line 55, in load_op_library
    ret = load_library.load_op_library(path)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 56, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename, status)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 473, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/../../_prefetching_ops.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE
```

Line 93 attempts to create an Estimator which causes the error.

```
tf.contrib.learn.Estimator(model_fn=convolutional_neural_network, model_dir="tmp")
```

I found a similar error on github but it was no help: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/684

Comment: The error message indicates a library version mismatch. So, the tutorial might not be right. Can you try Python 3.4?

Comment: I tried it with Python 2.7 and I encountered the same error. I did a fresh install of the os before that. https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b18204febd4c06d456681e913cceeb9c

Answer (score 0):

I installed an older build. It doesn't cause this error. http://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Nightly/job/nightly-pi/78/artifact/output-artifacts/tensorflow-1.3.0-cp27-none-any.whl